# DNN UrlRewrite ("DotNetNuke.HttpModules.UrlRewriteModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules") does not run custom rewrite rule on web.config

Tags: azure-web-app-service, dotnetnuke

On our DNN site hosted in an Azure app service, we have the following custom rule set on our web.config:

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
               <rule name="Proxy" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^base3/?(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://(a website hosted in aws s3)/tx/{R:1}" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST" value="{HTTP_HOST}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_X_Blog" value="1" />
                    </serverVariables>
                </rule> 

      </rules>
```

We have also setup the following in our `applicationHost.xdt`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">  
    <system.webServer>  
        <proxy xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" enabled="true" preserveHostHeader="false" reverseRewriteHostInResponseHeaders="false" />    
        <rewrite>
            <allowedServerVariables>
                <add name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST" xdt:Transform="Insert" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
                <add name="HTTP_X_UNPROXIED_URL" xdt:Transform="Insert" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>                
                <add name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" xdt:Transform="Insert" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
                <add name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" xdt:Transform="Insert" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>

                <add name="HTTP_X_Mischief" xdt:Transform="Insert" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
                <add name="HTTP_X_Blog" xdt:Transform="Insert" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>

            </allowedServerVariables>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

However, when trying to navigate to it (https://(our azure webapp.com)/base3/index.html) we constantly get the error **The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.** which is confusing because this was the rewrite rule we have used on our other sites.

We even tried the same approach on a fresh app service  and the rewrite rule above works just fine..

Trying to figure out what's wrong through heuristic analysis, on our web.config the rewrite rule now works if:

under `<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">`
then commenting  `<add name="UrlRewrite" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.UrlRewriteModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler" />`

However, the main site breaks now..

How do we implement a rewrite rule that works properly with `DotNetNuke.HttpModules.UrlRewriteModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules`??

Comment: You can first try to deploy on the local IIS, after installing the url rewrite module, see if it takes effect to ensure that the program is correct.

Comment: hi @Jason, followed your advice and yes the rewrite is working. This rewrite is also set up in another azure app service. What is your advise on dealing with this problem?

Comment: I also find url rewrite is not working in azure.  Maybe you can use application gateway to set up the rules of url rewrite.^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

```
 <configSections>
     <section name="RewriterConfig" type="URLRewriter.Config.RewriterConfigSerializerSectionHandler,URLRewriter" />
 </configSections>
 ......
 <RewriterConfig>
    <Rules>
       <RewriterRule>
         <LookFor>^default/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)</LookFor>
         <SendTo>11.aspx?id={R:1}</SendTo>
       </RewriterRule>
    </Rules>
 </RewriterConfig>
```

[image]

**PRIVIOUS**

About the function of url rewrite, the reason is the Web Server integrated by App Service cannot have full control. You can refer my answer in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61372611/azure-web-app-angular-not-redirecting-to-www/61380547#61380547) .

You can use the Application Gateway to implement the url rewriting function.

Comment: This is interesting... okay we'll check out application gateway

Comment: @MalcolmSalvador I also find Azure Front Door has function of url rewrite, you can see it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-url-rewrite

Comment: hi @Jason what's strange however is that on our other DNN sites, the rewrite rule we did to perform reverse proxy works, but somehow for this site it does not.. Trying both ideas, and will respond here for the final solution we implemented

Comment: @MalcolmSalvadorm Okey, I have update my answer. I also deployed my demo in azure. The url rewrite function seems to take effect in my demo.

Comment: @MalcolmSalvador You can try it, modify your web.config.

Comment: @MalcolmSalvador The solution I provided should be effective, you can try it. The same issue was resolved in another post. You can refer to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61372611/azure-web-app-angular-not-redirecting-to-www/61380547#61380547

Comment: @MalcolmSalvador You don't need to use `application gateway` and `front door` to deal with the problem of url rewrite.

Comment: We actually in the end went with azure frontoor, as with that we get the benefits of a CDN as well