# Azure Web App Angular Not redirecting to www

Tags: angularjs, azure, url-rewriting, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have the following in my web.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" appendQueryString="true"/>
          </rule>
          <rule name="Redirect to www" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="(.*)" />
              <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydomain.com$" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" 
                url="{MapProtocol:{HTTPS}}://www.mydomain.com/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
          <rewriteMaps>
            <rewriteMap name="MapProtocol">
              <add key="on" value="https" />
              <add key="off" value="http" />
            </rewriteMap>
        </rewriteMaps>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have the following in my assets in my angular.json

```
    "assets": [
      "src/favicon.ico",
      "src/assets",
      "src/web.config"
    ],
```

But my app does not redirect.

The issues is i have a App Service managed cert setup for www.mydomain.com

I have two custom domains setup
www.mydomain.com (this one allows me to add the binding to the app service cert)
mydomain.com (is unbound as I cant add a cert)

So I thought I could fix it with the redirect to always go to www. but it does not seem to work

Comment: I have update my answer,  without use application gateway and front door. You can try it, 
and if you need further help, pls  let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You can `RewriterConfig` to set url rewrite function in web.config file. More details you can see my answer in anothor [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61354328/dnn-urlrewrite-dotnetnuke-httpmodules-urlrewritemodule-dotnetnuke-httpmodules/61380845#61380845) .

**PRIVIOUS**

The Web Server integrated by App Service cannot have full control, which is one of the attributes of PaaS products.

App Service can only use some functions of IIS. It needs to be configured in the web.config file under `/site/wwwroot` (that is, the root directory of the project you develop).
All available IIS functions can only be configured through the `web.config` file.

**solution:**

• Try to add redirect rule in the web config file. If it fails, you can only use the rewrite feature of the application gateway.

• The following are some documents of Application Gateway about rewrite feature for your reference.

[Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/redirect-overview)

[Redirect web traffic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-url-redirect-cli)

[Troubleshoot--App service issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/troubleshoot-app-service-redirection-app-service-url)

Comment: I have the web.config file but its under wwwRoot>>Package>>WebsiteName>>dist>>web.config, does it always have to be under the root? Can i manually add one there?

Comment: I think you should put the contents of the dist folder under the wwwroot path.@MicroMan

Comment: thats where i have it and te above redirect is in there, but no joy...

Comment: Okey, I have test the function of url rewrite in app service. Just configure it in web.config, it works in iis which install URL rewrite module, but not in azure. So I suggest you to use application gateway.  In this service, there has the same function which maybe you want.@MicroMan

Comment: You should set the configuration of the url rewrite part in web.config in the application gateway, then it should be able to be used normally. Rather than just setting it in web.config, the configuration in the web.config file is only for local testing.@MicroMan

Comment: Can you share what you did in the application gateway, screenshots maybe?

Comment: @MicroMan Okey, I will try. I'm not familiar with angular. You also can read document of [Azure Front Door](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-url-rewrite).

Comment: I try it by myself, and seems success. You can refer my answer in another post, hope it useful yo u.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61354328/dnn-urlrewrite-dotnetnuke-httpmodules-urlrewritemodule-dotnetnuke-httpmodules/61380845#61380845

Comment: @MicroMan Have you read my answer? I don't know if it will help you. If it still doesn't take effect, I will try application gateway and front door.

Comment: @MicroMan Is the new solution I provided useful?