# Php HTTP redirect not working on Azure App Service

Tags: php, azure, apache, http, https

I'm trying to redirect my user to a certain website when they visit one of my end point.
https://url-shortner-in.azurewebsites.net/openfb will point to google.com

My server is hosted on Azure App Service with Slim Framework v4 using REST API.

This is my call to redirect the user.

```
return $response
            ->withHeader('Location', 'http://www.google.com')
            ->withStatus(302);
```

It's working fine on my local WAMP server. I'm getting redirected to Google.

But after uploading it on Azure App Service, the code isn't working.
I'm seeing a blank page after redirection. The URL stays the same (my website URL and not Google's.)

Is there any misconfiguration with Azure?

My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Did you get any hints from php's error.log? Or is it possible to use "display_errors" with ini_set("display_errors",1); so that you can probably see an error, warning or notice?

Comment: There's no error in my Azure error logs. I also checked the return header, turns out it's status 200 OK with blank body.

Comment: https://url-shortner-in.azurewebsites.net/openfb

Comment: This is the URL. I guess there's some misconfiguration with my .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you choose windows platform when create webapps.

You can try to create `web.config` file under the wwwroot folder, if it doesn't exist. If you can find this file when deployed your webapp, you need to modify it.

The specific content to be added or modified is that `RewriterConfig` needs to be added to web.config.

**The format is as follows:**

```
<configSections>
 <section name="RewriterConfig" type="URLRewriter.Config.RewriterConfigSerializerSectionHandler,URLRewriter" />
</configSections>
......
<RewriterConfig>
   <Rules>
      <RewriterRule>
        <LookFor>^default/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)</LookFor>
        <SendTo>11.aspx?id={R:1}</SendTo>
      </RewriterRule>
   </Rules>
</RewriterConfig>
```

For more details, you can refer to the following two posts:

[Azure Web App Angular Not redirecting to www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61372611/azure-web-app-angular-not-redirecting-to-www/61380547#61380547)

[DNN UrlRewrite (“DotNetNuke.HttpModules.UrlRewriteModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules”) does not run custom rewrite rule on web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61354328/dnn-urlrewrite-dotnetnuke-httpmodules-urlrewritemodule-dotnetnuke-httpmodules/61380845#61380845)

Comment: Could I not run it on Linux? The web.config is not there in my root folder right now. Also, the format you wrote is for ASPX, right? I'll look for a php version.

Comment: Linux？Perhaps you need try it？

Comment: If not, I will try my best to help you !

Comment: Okay. I'm testing this now. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I tried doing some work at the codes and found that ("include/DbOperation.php") is causing some problem. When I remove the line, it's working fine. The DbOperation file is connecting to database and doing db operations.

Comment: Also, I've created a windows web app to test. Can you help me with the web.config file. My structure is: in the root, I've index.php which is using Slim Framework to create REST api.

Comment: I changed the server to windows and added web.config. It's working now. Thank you for the time.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**: Enable Apache .htaccess

***By default, the .htaccess file is not enabled.***

**1.** Open the default host configuration file by entering the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

**2.** Locate the section labeled `<Directory /var/www>`.
In that section, change the `AllowOverride None` entry to `all`:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Save the file and exit.

**3.** Next, **restart** the Apache service:

```
sudo systemctl apache2 restart
```

Comment: Hey not luck changing the setting. I handed it over to a friend who couldn't find a clue how to do that. We stuck looking for how to access the apache config. Tried it at mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/webssh/host. Can't find any of the available directory. Can we access Apache config in Azure Web App?

Comment: Hi, so I did some research on my codes. Turns out I'm including a file "require_once ("include/DbOperation.php");". When I remove this line, the code executes perfectly. In DbOperation.php,  I'm connecting to database and performing database operation.

Comment: I changed the server to windows and added web.config. It's working now. Thank you for the time.