# My Express route not working from browser

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, nginx, jenkins

My Angular application overriding node express route when triggered from browser. Its working fine when i tried same node route from postman.

When i hit my expressjs public route in browser then its redirecting me to default page of angular app.

Example,
if i hit below url in browser
**https://example.com/mj/api/get-details**

Its redirect me to default angular page instead of hitting nodejs route.
angular default page example,
**https://example.com/#/home**

All my exressjs routes working properly from postman. But its seems angular overriding express route.

How do i create express public route & access it from browser.

**Note**: my angular & node express(microservice) working different repositories.

Comment: Are you sure your node server is running on port 80 ?? or are you reverse proxying it with nginx

Comment: its running on different port & using nginx

Comment: One possibility maybe some extra header needed to API which is not getting while accessing browser and failing. So redirecting to the home page which is angular

Comment: i removed header's from nodejs but still not working

Comment: Pls check [my answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61354328/dnn-urlrewrite-dotnetnuke-httpmodules-urlrewritemodule-dotnetnuke-httpmodules/61380845#61380845), I hope it will useful to you.