# How do I get an Azure API App to work if published from Visual Studio 2019 without API Mgmt in between?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-api-apps

I am using Visual Studio 2019 ver 16.7.2.

I have an API Project that is called JobBank.API.  In Visual Studio, my App URL in the project settings is http://localhost://6705.  I also have a Swagger file created and configured in my Startup.cs as: "/swagger/JobBankOpenAPISpecification/swagger.json".

I published the API Project using Visual Studio to an Azure API App Service.  The URL is "http://jobbank-api-demo.azurewebsites.net.  After I publish it, a browser windows comes up to that URL with a 500 error saying "jobbank-api-demo.azurewebsites.net can't currently handle this request.".

Also when I try that url with "/swagger.json" I get a 500 error.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in the .net cores 2.0 version of this problem. The 3.1 version we are currently using, I personally tested it, and this problem should have been resolved.

**I will post my screenshot first to see if it is the result you want.**

[image]

From the pic, we can see I have deployed my test web on azure, and also can open `swagger.json` file, no `500 Error`.

So, I think you should check your code. You can [download my test code from github](https://github.com/Jason446620/swaggertest).

When you test my code, you should modify links in `index.html` file under `wwwroot` folder . And when you deploy the demo, you will get 404 error. Don't worry, you need to attach `/index.html` at the url.

When you finish all the operations, you will get the same result as mine.

**Details encountered when trying to solve your problem:**

When I modify default route in startup.cs file.

[image]

[image]

When I add these code in project, it will get `500 Error`. So If your code has same configurations, I suggest you remove it, and use **[`url rewrite`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61354328/dnn-urlrewrite-dotnetnuke-httpmodules-urlrewritemodule-dotnetnuke-httpmodules/61380845#61380845)**.

Comment: This is what I have in Startup.Config():
 
// call after UseHttpsRedirection
    app.UseSwagger();
 
    app.UseSwaggerUI(setupAction =>
    {
        setupAction.SwaggerEndpoint(
            "/swagger/JobAssistOpenAPISpecification/swagger.json",
            "ArticleBank API");
 
        setupAction.RoutePrefix = "swagger";
    });
 
    app.UseRouting();
 
    // app.UseAuthentication();
 
    app.UseAuthorization();
 
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}

Comment: Have you try my way ？